# DKIM signing key

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dkim, opendkim

when I create DKIM key like this:

> sudo opendkim-genkey -s mail -d example.com
>
> -s specifies the selector and -d the domain, this command will create two files, mail.private is our private key and mail.txt contains the
>   public key.

Should I insert domain from mail comes, or the domain assigned to mail server in -d selector? (in my case these are 2 different domains, because I want to send from various mail domains in the future)

Answer (score 3):

Your email domain. 
And you should publish public key via dns

DKIM provides a method for validating a domain name identity that is associated with a message through cryptographic authentication - so,in simple words that message from "user@example.com" really send (and wasn't modified in process) by example.com mail server. So - yes, you should have separate DKIM key pair for each doman.

Comment: Could you expand upon your answer to help the questioner understand the differences between the options?

Comment: So i should have separate DKIM signing keys for every e-mail domain and i should publish DKIM public key of it via TXT DNS? (I know how it should be done)

Comment: DKIM provides a method for validating a domain name identity that is associated with a message through cryptographic authentication - so,in simple words that message from "user@example.com" really send (and wasn't modified in process) by example.com mail server. So - yes, you should have separate DKIM key pair for each doman.

Comment: Hiraku, but for example I send mail from mail adress: mail@example.com but from mailserver: mail.example2.com (different domains). So i should provide keys for mail adress and include them in example.com DNS entries?

Comment: Yes, keys for all domains your hosted on your server. 
Key for example.com, key for example.org and etc

Comment: If I want to enable DKIM for all my customers with their bunch of domains, I have to generate Keys for all of those and urge them to set the DNS-Records for all of them? Isn't the specification of the allowed sender not already covered by SPF?

Comment: They are alike, but: SPF says where from email messages for domain can come from. DKIM defines that message was not modified in transit and confirms that sender belongs to domain.